# Grandparent, parent and child management issues with 'position: absolute'

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So as this is in React my code is always inside of the root div(grandparent).

In my Project.js component I have another `div(parent)` that just keeps the background color.

And that component is displayed in **App.js** without an extra div

All the elements inside the parent have position: absolute(except the first image which needs to be fixed as it is).

The elements with position absolute seem to be breaking out of the parent div.

At the bottom is the zoomed out picture of the current state .
The sandy area in the image is the div with that background color.

I've tried setting grandparent and parent to position: relative didnt work.
tried setting parent to overflow:hidden hoping it would expand? that doesnt work

**App.js:** (ignore home component)

```
import Home from './components/Home'
import Project from './components/Projects';
function App() {
    return(
        <>
            <Home />
            <Project />
        </>
    )
}
```

The project Component: (the children are set to position absolute in my css file)

```
class Project extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {}
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div >
                <img src={ocean} alt="" />
                <h1 className={a}> Projects</h1>
                <h2 className={b}> Desktop, Tablet and Mobile Responsive</h2>
                <img src={pframe} alt="" className={c}/>
                <img src={um} alt="" className={d}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.a{     
    position: absolute;
    width: 278px;
    height: 83px;
    left: 184px;
    top: 1330px;
    font-family: Viga;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 72px;
    line-height: 97px;
    color: rgba(87, 6, 38, 0.98);
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 4px #FFD482;
}

.b{
    position: absolute;
    width: 617px;
    height: 33px;
    left: 178px;
    top: 1425px;
    font-family: Viga;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 34px;
    line-height: 46px;
    color: #F54900;
    text-shadow: 2px 4px 0px #F7E5B6;
}

.c{
    position: absolute;
    width: 758px;
    height: 644.52px;
    left: 77px;
    top: 1586px;
}

.d{
    position: absolute;
    width: 782.67px;
    height: 832.35px;
    left: 700px;
    top: 1232.65px;
}
```

I want the parent to expand with the child content. 
While the children are positioned `absolute`, as I will be updating the content.

So setting a height to the parent doesn't seem to be the right thing to do.[image]

Comment: could you please provide the resulting html and your css/scss?

Comment: updated it with the css just now, the rest i've included already

Comment: sorry but the react template is not the resulting html. If you could set up a fiddle with images, then it would be easier to catch the issue. What is "parent and child content"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now i got what you mean.
to make the parent div growth with its child contents, you can position the child elements "relative" instead of absolute.

the parent div then set to style="overflow: overlay;"

instead of overflow:auto you can try "overlay"

Comment: alright that seems to work my svgs and all the content are inside the div now which is brilliant but one problem is that it has created two more schrollbars for that div so now i have total of 3 schrollbars

Comment: please try  style="overflow: overlay;"

Comment: great that gets rid of the schrollbars
but i think position relative got rid of my pictures overlapping
i want them to overlap. just like the last image i provided. do you know how I could achieve that without position: absolute?

Comment: Actually i do not catch your question but maybe: feel free to put a particular image to position=absolute instead.

Comment: thanks for the help Matt! with changes here and there i've finally put it all together

Answer (score 0):

use `overflow: initial` in your relative `div`